# IE6 HTML control wrapping

Tags: html, controls, word-wrap, internet-explorer-6

Is there any way to prevent wrapping across controls in IE6?  For example, I have a label and a single select box.  The select box width is dynamic (depending on the content).  I want the label to always be to the left of the select box.  Right now the problem I am having is the select box drops below the label.  I have tried using the `<nobr>` tag as well as CSS word-wrap rules, but because this isn't text the wrapping rules do not apply.  The only way I have found for sure to make it work is to place them in a two-column table, but I do not like this solution.  Is there any other way?

Comment: Was the answer below sufficient?  Did you figure out your problem?

Comment: No, but I appreciate the tip!  I found a solution that did work, though.

Answer (score 1):

If both the label and the input have an inline display ("display: inline;") and the input is breaking to a new line, then chances are the parent container is too narrow.  With that said, typical horizontal-label form layouts don't rely on this inline display, they take a more controlled approach utilizing block-level, floated elements.  For example, given the following HTML:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="fieldId">field label</label> 
    <input id="fieldId" name="field" />
</div>
```

You could set the position of the label with the following CSS:

```
.field {
    overflow: hidden; /* clear float */
}
.field label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

There's a [ton of variations](http://www.google.com/search?q=good+form+html+css) on the specifics, but the above conveys the basic concept.